# Create a new file type for arranging by type in finder

Tags: finder, file-extensions

When I arrange my files by type in Finder, I have several classes like folders, documents, images... and others.

[image: Files arranged by type]

However, all my `.tex` files are in others (*Autres*) and I want them to be grouped in a specific class. Is there a way to do this?